# Javascript json api call

Tags: javascript

I want to make an api call to a JSON ( https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune ) , by passing it a city name(hard coded) and get the latitude and longitude in return. I have attempted the code mentioned below.

```
function loadJSON(callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune", true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    };
    xobj.send();
  }

  function init() {
    loadJSON(function(response) {
      // Parse JSON string into object
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest.lat);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest.lng);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lng);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lat);
      alert(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lng);

    });
  }
```

Comment: You've shared some code, but you haven't described what problem you're having. Is there an error? Do you see output? Is the output different from what you expected?

Comment: Also, looks like you're missing a closing curly brace for `loadJSON`. Is this the actual exact code you're trying to run?

Comment: Your `xobj.send()` is also in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi smarx! Yes I am facing an error. Also the expected output is supposed to be the latitude and longitude of the city sent in the query string. And further i need to pass these lattitudes and longitudes to another api call to get the formatted address.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I use the output of this call to print the formatted address as well??

Comment: "I am facing an error." And is that error a secret? I don't know how you expect people to help you when you won't tell them what the error is. (It was possibly a syntax error because you were missing a curly brace, if this is in fact the exact code you're trying to run.) In the future, please share the exact code you're running and the exact error message you receive.

Comment: "Can you tell me how do I use the output of this call to print the formatted address as well??" No. I don't even know wha that means. (Didn't you *start* with an address?) Regardless, that would be a separate question, so please ask a new question once you've formulated a good one.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues in your code:

1. You were missing the closing curly brace for `loadJSON`.
2. `xobj.send()` was in the wrong place... it needs to be outside of the `onreadystatechange` function.
3. You were using `this.responseText` in your callback instead of the parameter you were passing in.

I fixed those issues, converted the `alert`s to `console.log`s, and got rid of the needless `overrideMimeType` call. Working code is below:

```js
function loadJSON(callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.open("GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune", true);
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    };
  }
  xobj.send();
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(responseText) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(responseText);

      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lng);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest.lat);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.bounds.southwest.lng);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.location.lng);

      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lng);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lat);
      console.log(myObj.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest.lng);

    });
}

init();
```

Comment: Thanks smarx!! :) Also I need to know if there's a way where i can pass one of the latitude and longitude values as arguments and then use them to get the formatted address from the JSON.